# Node js always running

Tags: node.js, titanium, forever

i am trying to build my project in titanium, but i always get this error.

> events.js:72
>           throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>                 ^ Error: spawn ENOENT
>       at errnoException (child_process.js:988:11)
>       at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:779:34) [rayhan@localhost test]$ appl

Googling brought me to the conclusion that another node.js process is listening at the same port.
so i tried to see which process is running using

```
ps aus | grep node
```

i always get a different pid:

```
[rayhan@localhost test]$ ps aux | grep node
rayhan    **1146**  0.0  0.0   8952   660 pts/0    S+   12:26   0:00 grep node

[rayhan@localhost test]$ ps aux | grep node
rayhan    **1148**  0.0  0.0   8952   660 pts/0    S+   12:26   0:00 grep node

[rayhan@localhost test]$ ps aux | grep node
rayhan    **1150**  0.0  0.0   8952   656 pts/0    S+   12:26   0:00 grep node

[rayhan@localhost test]$ ps aux | grep node
rayhan    **1152**  0.0  0.0   8952   660 pts/0    S+   12:26   0:00 grep node
```

i tried to use

```
forever list
info:    No forever processes running
```

what can be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: The code is the sample that is generated with "titanium create"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pid you're looking at is for the `grep node` process, which is why it's different every time. There doesn't appear to be a node process running, so your problem is elsewhere. Without seeing any of your code, we can't really help you further.

[updated]

The error isn't very verbose, but it looks like it's trying to spawn a sub-process and failing. If you try spawn a sub-process for a command for an executable that doesn't exist, this is the type of error that will occur. I'm going to take a wild guess here and assume you haven't installed one or more dependencies required by titanium, or your environment PATH does not contain the directory to the dependant executables.

Have you read this page: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Setting_up_the_Titanium_CLI

Comment: The code is the sample that is generated with "titanium create"